# AdMob Mediation reward video ad Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 No ad returned from any ad server

Tags: ios

I use Google AdMob Mediation for iOS, load reward video ad returns error, error code is `9`, message is:

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 "No ad returned from any ad server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No ad returned from any ad server., NSLocalizedFailureReason=No ad returned from any ad server.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually returned for a couple of reasons.

- There were no ads that are available to serve the specific user.
- Content width is not enough for the ad to be shown fully
- You just created the ad element at AdMob and it'll take some time before it'll start serving you ads.
- You are using the wrong `App ID` or `ID`. Just double check them as you might have just copied the example from documentation and forgot to change it to your unit's `app id` or `id`.
- Last but not least, you didn't properly initialize the AdMob. Go back and read the documentation again.