# Rewarded Video Ads not displaying?

Tags: ios, swift, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have implemented whole procedure of Google doc for Reward AbMob integration. 
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video

But i am getting error like this:- 
Reward based video ad failed to load: No ad returned from any ad server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdMob Mediation reward video ad Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 No ad returned from any ad server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683880/admob-mediation-reward-video-ad-error-domain-com-google-ads-code-9-no-ad-returne)

Answer (score 0):

Note : you have to replace kSampleAdUnitID with your AppID in Admob

Its obious that there are no ads for the user, google only send ads for a person on its recent search.

Google is also promoting firebase ads instead admob.

and of-corse, did you create a proper frame for your adview, there are multiple type of ads, 
one which comes on banner,
second which comes on any grid,
and last which comes on whole screen

So, each type should have a specific dimension view. Please check it.